# How to get ID from selected CLASS while scrolling to perticular Section

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to get ID of section when I'm scrolling my webpage in Parallax website.
When scroll will hit end of section then I want to take ID of that selected section.

**HTML**

```
<section id="section1" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
<section id="section2" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
<section id="section3" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
<section id="section4" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.content').offset().top + $('.content').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
          alert('end reached');
          //How to get ID here I have tried like this but no result:
            //$(this).attr("id");
            //$(this).closest("section").attr("id"); 
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`, `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`,  `parseInt()`, `.prev()`, `.is()` to check if element `.bottom` is greater than or equal to `height` of element. If previous element has same `.className` as filtered element, set variable to previous element, else to last element in collection.

```
var content = $(".content");
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    var el = content.filter(function(i, el) {
      return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= parseInt($(el).css("height"))
    })
    , sectionId = el.prev(".content").is(content) 
                  ? el.prev(".content").attr("id") 
                  : content.eq(-1).attr("id");
    console.log(sectionId);
}).scroll();
```

```js
var content = $(".content");
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    var el = content.filter(function(i, el) {
      return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= parseInt($(el).css("height"))
    })
    , sectionId = el.prev().is(content) 
                  ? el.prev(".content").attr("id") 
                  : content.eq(-1).attr("id");
    console.log(sectionId);
}).scroll();
```

```css
.content {
  height:200px;
  display:block;
}:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1" class="content" >
   blah blah
</section>
<section id="section2" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
<section id="section3" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
<section id="section4" class="content" >
    blah blah
</section>
```