# Most efficient way to detect current element in scroll navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Im not sure how to find what I need (name it) so I count on you to explain it for me.

I need to create javascript content navigation based on "post" or "comment" system. First of all I want to emphasize that content is not plain text but It contain HTML, images and other objects that can resize during usage.

**How does it look?**
One container for content divided to sections and one for dedicated navigation scroll - this scroll is snapped relatively to sections.

[image]

Whole system is very simillar to discourse posts navigation -
[check discourse here](https://try.discourse.org/)

- Most important thing for me is to keep synchronization for scroll and content.
- If you click 3th post in scroll, content should scroll to this post - this is easy.
- If you scroll by mouse content is scrolled + dedicated navigation is automatically synchronised - this is my problem I think.

**What is the best* way to check which one section is my current section.
Should I find visible element? bounding rectangle? calculate it based on heights of all sections?**

PS If you have any library working in similar way you can post it as addition - it can be helpful for me.

**//edit**

***best** - simple, not too slow if I get more elements (100-1000), takes into consideration dynamic content (resize) and also supported by all modern browsers. Probably there is more than 3 methods but if you post more alternatives, Me or someone else can pick suitable solution.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/alssndro/page-scroll-indicator

Comment: You should trac users scroll position and compare it to element position. If scroll top offset is equal to element position - it's active.

Comment: Here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative

Comment: Oh yeah - rly helpful! From this answer i see I have to just check all elements is there any other way ?

Comment: You can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`, see [How to get ID from selected CLASS while scrolling to perticular Section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598778/how-to-get-id-from-selected-class-while-scrolling-to-perticular-section/)

Comment: Yeah I seen somwhere this method but my question is what is most effective/fastest and dont fail (no bugs etc) - just best method to do it (and why).

Comment: _"but my question is what is most effective/fastest"_ Compared to which approaches? _"and dont fail (no bugs etc)"_ How can this be verified absolutely? _"just best method to do it (and why)."_ What is the definition of "best"? How is "best" determined?  Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Best, hm.. I think for example - its not too slow if I have more than 500 elements or It works in all modern browsers. Anyway I didnt give you definition of "best" - true, I will add it to queston. I don't have js code for this example - first I wanted to see some ideas for it. For me if you post that as answer + short description like: "Working in all browsers and its rly fast method cos something" is enough.